# Does Stroop test performance correlate with any personal characteristics or abilities?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, test, attention, correlation

Have there been any studies that found that an extremely high (or low) [Stroop test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect) score correlates with certain personal characteristics, abilities or aptitudes, or would all such conclusions be outside the test's scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N.B.: There are many varieties of "Stroop-like" tasks, which as a class are often called implicit association tests or IATs.  Since those are likely to test attributes related to their specific construction, I have excluded them from this answer.

There have been a variety of papers studying correlations of Stroop performance with other characteristics.

Ward et al. (2001) examined the correlation between Stroop effects and executive control, finding that **Stroop costs and other measures of executive control were not well correlated**.

Brewer et al. (2008) found **sizable correlations between neural activation in Stroop testing and treatment outcomes among cocaine-dependent patients**; they interpret this to suggest executive control differences are determinative in treatment outcome, but this interpretation is contradicted by Ward et al. above.

Less recently, Golden (1975) found the **Stroop test to correlate with measures of creativity**; I have found no more recent discussion of this so cannot speak to its currency.

References
Ward, G., Roberts, M., & Phillips, L. (2001). Task-switching costs, Stroop-costs, and executive control: A correlational study. The Quarterly Journal of Experimental Psychology Section A: Human Experimental Psychology Volume 54, Issue 2, pages 491-511. DOI:10.1080/713755967

Brewer, J., et al. (2008). Pretreatment Brain Activation During Stroop Task Is Associated with Outcomes in Cocaine-Dependent Patients. Biological Psychiatry Volume 64, Issue 11, 1 December 2008, Pages 998–1004. doi:10.1016/j.biopsych.2008.05.024

Golden, C. (1975). The Measurement of Creativity by the Stroop Color and Word Test. Journal of Personality Assessment. Journal of Personality Assessment Volume 39, Issue 5, 1975 pages 502-506. DOI: 10.1207/s15327752jpa3905_9

Answer (score 1):

The Stroop test also correlates with age and education level (Van der Elst et al. 2006).

When emotionally charged words are presented (Emo-Stroop), the Stroop task was found to correalte with high state anxiety.(Dresler et al 2009)

You can find a review in "Secondary Influences on Neuropsychological Test Performance", edited by Peter Arnett. (Its on google books)

references:
Wim Van der Elst, Martin P. J. Van Boxtel, Gerard J. P. Van Breukelen, Jelle Jolles (2006) The Stroop color-word test: influence of age, sex, and education; and normative data for a large sample across the adult age range. Assessment. Vol 13, Issue 1, Mar 2006, Pages 62-79.

Thomas Dresler, Katja Mériau, Hauke R. Heekeren, Elke van der Meer (2009) Emotional Stroop task: effect of word arousal and subject anxiety on emotional interference Psychological Research Vol 73, Pages 364–371